# Oracle - truncate date partition if the partition exists

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle 12. I have a table which is partitioned by column `dt` which is `DATE` type.
For partitioning I've used the following syntax:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (dt) (
partition part_01 values less than (DATE '2023-08-01')
)
```

So other partitions are created automatically for each dt.

The task is:
***I need to check if the partition for a particular date exists and if so, truncate the partition.***

I can't directly use partition name because it doesn't contain any information about date (naming pattern is default and is like `SYS_PXXXXXXX`).

So I try to use `user_tab_partition` view. Column `high_value` of that view contain the highest `dt` for rows stored in that partition.

As `high_value` column data type is `long` first I have to write the code using `dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype` function to get XML-representation of available `high_values` values, then parse it and get the date that I need.
That looks too complicated for such a simple task.

***What's the best way for designing such a routine?***

*Maybe a better approach is to manually control the partitions names when they are created (and hence be able to access them in an easy way)?*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73260090/oracle-db-portioning-delete-with-automation